# tweak openURL in UIApplication (CaptainHook)

Tags: objective-c, ios5, hook, jailbreak, tweak

how i can load a hook in UIApplication?

```
#import <CaptainHook/CaptainHook.h>
#import <SpringBoard/SpringBoard.h>

CHDeclareClass(SBAlertWindow);
CHOptimizedMethod(1, self, void, SBAlertWindow, displayAlert, id, alert) {
    NSLog(@"load displayAlert!");
    CHSuper(1, SBAlertWindow, displayAlert, alert);
}

CHDeclareClass(UIApplication)
CHOptimizedMethod(1, self, void, UIApplication, openURL, NSURL *, url) {
    NSString *linkToOpen = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:[url absoluteString]];
    NSLog(@"dont load link: %@", linkToOpen);
    CHSuper(1, UIApplication, openURL, url);        
}

CHConstructor {
    CHLoadLateClass(SBAlertWindow);
    CHHook(1, SBAlertWindow, displayAlert);

    CHLoadLateClass(UIApplication);
    CHHook(1, UIApplication, openURL);
}
```

In my test with SBAlertWindow. 
work perfect.
but openURL in UIApplication dont hook.

need some config in makefile?

Answer (score 0):

Import the header file that has that implementation from these dumps https://github.com/Fr0stDev/SpringBoard-iOS5-Headers.

I do not know the excatct method used but it would look somthing like

```
-(void)openURl:(NSUrl*)url;
```

add that method in your tweak and do what you please

```
-(void)openURl:(NSUrl*)url{

UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Open Url?" message:@"Tweak 
over rides the method and called an alertview. What do you want to do?" delegate:self 
cancelButtonTitle:@"No Thanks" otherButtonTitles:@"Copy Link", @"Save",@"ViewSaved", 
nil];
[alert show];
[alert release];

return Url;


}
```

Answer (score 0):

KHookObjectWrapper.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface KHookObjectWrapper : NSObject

+ (void)initialize;
- (BOOL)fake__openURL:(NSURL *)url;

@end
```

KHookObjectWrapper.m

```
#import "KHookObjectWrapper.h"
#import <objc/objc.h>
#import <objc/runtime.h>

@implementation KHookObjectWrapper

+ (void)initialize
{
Method openURL = class_getInstanceMethod([UIApplication class], @selector(openURL:));
Method openURLMy = class_getInstanceMethod([self class], @selector(openURLHooked:));
IMP openURLImp = method_getImplementation(openURL);
class_addMethod([UIApplication class], @selector(fake__openURL:), openURLImp, method_getTypeEncoding(openURL));
IMP openURLSelfImp = method_getImplementation(openURLMy);
class_replaceMethod([UIApplication class], @selector(openURL:), openURLSelfImp, method_getTypeEncoding(openURL));
}

//fake method, never run.
- (BOOL)fake__openURL:(NSURL *)url
{
abort();
return YES;
}

- (BOOL)openURLHooked:(NSURL *)url
{
NSLog(@"openURL param:url=%@", [url absoluteString]);
return [self fake__openURL:url];
}

@end
```

at last, add code in your main appDelegate.m

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    [KHookObjectWrapper initialize];
    ...
}
```